# Is it possible to recover after losing the checkpoint coordinator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using incremental checkpoint with RocksDB and saving the checkpoints into a remote destination(S3 in my case).
What will happen if someone deletes the job manager server (where the checkpoint coordinator operates) and reinstall it?
By losing the checkpoint coordinator I also lose the option to recover the state from the checkpoints? because from what I know,
the coordinator holds all the references of the checkpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Flink with [high availability](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html) enabled, then Flink will store pointers to its checkpoints in ZooKeeper. In case of a `JobManager` failure, Flink will recover all checkpoints from ZooKeeper and be able to resume the jobs from the latest completed checkpoint.