# Apache Flink - FsStateBackend - How state is recovered in case of Task Manager failure which stores state in its local file system

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-statefun

Assume we have 2 Job Managers (ZooKeeper for HA) and 3 Task Managers. I have configured FsStateBackend for checkpointing. I assume that the FsStateBackend runs in each of the Task Managers which maintains the state in the memory. Upon checkpoint, the state is persisted in the path which we have configured(file:/data). Basically I have configured the path pointing to the local file system. So each of the Task Managers has its own local disk storage where checkpointed data is persisted. As per my understanding a small meta data is sent to Job Manager on checkpointing.

1. What happens If one of the Task Manager crashes? It is for sure that the tasks are started in any of the available Task Managers. How is the job state recovered since the Task Manager's (Task Manager which crashed) checkpointed data is not available since it is down? Does the checkpoint process send the state information to Job Manager?
2. What is the metadata sent by Task Manager to Job Manager during the checkpointing?
3. Does the file system which we are using is supposed to be distributed state? E.g. NFS, S3. What happens If we use the systems local storage for checkpointing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use a distributed file system for checkpointing. Something like HDFS, S3, GFS, NFS, Ceph, etc. Furthermore, the storage path used must be accessible from all participating processes/nodes (i.e. all Task Managers and Job Managers).

Otherwise, as you've pointed out, the checkpoint data would be lost if a local disk failed.

The Job Manager has complete knowledge concerning checkpointing, and if you have HA configured, this information is stored in the configured HA storage provider in order to enable Job Manager failover.

Comment: We are configuring two paths in flink-conf.yaml which are high-availability.storageDir and state.checkpoints.dir. As per your comment, it looks like both of the paths should be a distributed directory. Am I right? Lets says I havn't enabled checkpoint for any of my jobs. If this is the case, will there be any data persisted in high-availability.storageDir or state.checkpoints.dir? I assume that since the checkpoint isn't enabled there is no state to persist in state.checkpoints.dir. Since there is no state, nothing is stored in high-availability.storageDir. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, both high-availability.storageDir and state.checkpoints.dir should point to durable storage. Of course, if you aren't checkpointing, then the state.checkpoints.dir won't be used. HA is off by default, so if it not configured, any specification for high-availability.storageDir will be ignored. But if HA is configured, the high-availability.storageDir may be used for leader election even if checkpointing is disabled.

Comment: I have configured HA for which I am planning to either use AWS EFS or Rocks DB (with S3)? Which one do you think is better? As per my understanding, checkpointing will trigger heavy write operation and read will happen only in case of task failure. Will HA create read or write heavy operations in high-availability.storageDir?

Comment: Flink uses the term "high availability" to mean nothing more or less than Job Manager failover. The storage and i/o involved are minimal. RocksDB has nothing to do with HA. Checkpointing is something else -- this is about recovering from job and Task Manager failures.

Comment: This is too big a topic to address in a comment. See these answers for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59705241/2000823, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615808/2000823, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55615858/2000823. For info on choosing a state backend, and how to configure it, register for the free training at https://training.ververica.com, and then read through https://training.ververica.com/decks/runtime, especially the second half.